# Naruto fanfiction where the Kyuubi is female

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, naruto

All I know for sure is that I read the summary of the story on fanfiction.net, earlier this month, and the summary said something about centuries, and I'm paraphrasing here because I don't remember what it exactly said but here's what it said, "And yes, She." Something like that, also as far as I know it wasn't a Naruto X Kurama fic.

Comment: Hmm... there's a fair number of them where the Kyuubi is female.

Comment: Did you try looking at your browsing history?

Comment: Please don't entirely reword your post into an all-new question, invalidating the existing answers. See [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12310/98028) explaining why such an action isinappropriate. Ask a new question instead. If by any chance you're not able to post new questions, see [this other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/398063).

Comment: Except I can't since my questions so far have been considered too vague to answer, so I can no longer ask new questions, and I no longer care about the answer to the original question in the first place.

Comment: Well, that still doesn't allow you to deface your earlier posts I'm afraid. Whether you care about the original question/answer or not, people have deemed them useful for the site by upvoting them, so you can't go this way. Please read [this guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/398063) on how to get out of a question ban, and note that in any case, you'll be able to ask a new question in six months anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This might be "[The Teenage Kyuubi](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/11485433/1/The-teenage-kyuubi)"

> And yes, she, the kyuubi is a girl. ... The female kyuubi ... Kyuubi. Now read on. We find the Kaze no torio (I'm using the Kaze no torio for the trio ...

Unfortunately, I've only found this excerpt via cached Google searches. It looks like the author may have taken it down.

Another excerpt from the page, found with a slightly different search:

> Wait, maybe this is a trap and they are going to do something awful to ... to write an alternate version of this fanfiction called 'The Creationist', ...

but unfortunately, I haven't found anything that matches that either.

Comment: That's the closest summary to what I remember, but it's not quite right.

Answer (score 2):

[Naruto Genkyouien](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4730390/1/Naruto-Genkyouien) by Daniel Rush is a likely suspect here. When browsing Naruto fics sorted by Favorites, this one is in the top 100, and its description matches the "Yes, she." point of the question, though it lacks any mention of "centuries".

> The nine-tailed demon fox. Its mighty tails can crumble mountains, cause tsunamis, and set things on fire. Lots of fire. It might have been better if she actually were an evil entity bent on destroying the world. Yes, she. AU pseudo-x-over.

Also, Naruto and the Kyuubi do not become romantically entangled over the course of the fic.